# Django excluding an article from query

Tags: python, html, django

I have a query set called most_viewed, and it is a list of just one element. I want to exclude this in the other articles section as this will be in the main section. The error I receive is "Not enough values to unpack". Here is the code of my view. How do I go about fixing this?

```
def home_view(request):
    title = 'Home'
    most_viewed = Post.objects.order_by('-views')[0:1]
    articles = Post.objects.all().exclude(most_viewed).order_by('-date_posted')[0:3]
```

Comment: try `.exclude(id=most_viewed.id)`

Comment: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'id'
I suppose since the most_viewed is a list it set this error. I fixed it by doing [0]! thanks!

Comment: yeah its because you have a list. sorry, didnt pay attention there. you could use `first()` instead of [0] if you want to do it the "django" way but your solution if just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `most_viewed` is a queryset (that contains zero or one items), so you can exclude this with the [**`__in`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in):

```
def home_view(request):
    title = 'Home'
    most_viewed = Post.objects.order_by('-views')[0:1]
    articles = Post.objects.exclude(
        id__in=most_viewed
    ).order_by('-date_posted')[0:3]
```

Or you can do this in two queries with:

```
def home_view(request):
    title = 'Home'
    most_viewed = Post.objects.order_by('-views').values('pk').first()
    articles = Post.objects.exclude(
        id=most_viewed
    ).order_by('-date_posted')[0:3]
```

This is also safe if there are no `Post` objects, since then `most_viewed` is `None`, so it will not error.